# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (10,3,32,32)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am getting the reshape error and I am not sure how to fix it. Here is what I have done so far. Any advice what I done wrong? Thank you!

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

dataset_folder_path = 'cifar-10-batches-py'

labels = []
data = []
alllabels = []
alldata = []

    for i in range(1,6): 
        print("procesing file ", '/data_batch_' + str(i))
        with open(dataset_folder_path + '/data_batch_' + str(i), mode='rb')as file:
        my_data = (pickle.load(file, encoding='latin1'))        
        labels = my_data['labels']
        alllabels = np.append(alllabels,labels)

        data = my_data['data']
        alldata = np.append(alldata, data)


   def getbatch(alldata, alllabels, batch_size = 16):
        print(batch_size)
        for start in range(0, len(alldata), batch_size):
            end = min(start + batch_size, len(alldata))
            yield (alldata[start:end], alllabels[start:end])


    batchsize = 10
    for x, y in getbatch(alldata, alllabels, batchsize):
        x = x.reshape(batchsize, 3, 32, 32)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like you are using reshape correctly. It only calls for three parameters. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Comment: yes but look at this solution line 33: https://github.com/deep-diver/CIFAR10-img-classification-tensorflow/blob/master/CIFAR10_image_classification.py. 4 parameters are uses for reshape.

Comment: what is `x.shape` and `batchsize`? There's no problem with putting 4 parameters in reshape afaik. but `x.size` must equal `batchsize*3*32*32` I reckon

Comment: the shape of data is (10000, 3072) and when all arrays are appended the shape of alldata should be (5000, 3072) and if would so then everything would work. Instead the np.append brakes shape and  as a result x.shape = (153600000,). I am not sure how to append np arrays without breaking the shape and why it does brake shape?

Comment: No, he is using a `tuple` with 4 values and you are using `reshape` with 4 parameters. He is actually only using 1 parameter, which is possible with `reshape`.